# Using arctan to prove equivalence of 3 definitions of a manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

My uncle is mathematician and a bit of a wise guy. He challenged me to use the properties of arctan to answer a particular problem but I have no idea what I'm looking for or why arctan is a good choice for this. Can someone help me see how I might use the properties of arctan in the following problem?

The Problem:

Consider the usual definition of a topological manifold and in particular the part about the homeomorphism.  We are given the following propositions and asked to show that they yield equivalent definitions of a manifold, that is equivalent definitions can be obtained with each. My uncle says this means showing $A \Rightarrow B \Rightarrow C$ or vice versa.

Proposition A: 
Each point has a neighborhood that is homeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Proposition B: 
Each point has a neighborhood that is homeomorphic to an open $n$-ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Proposition C: 
Each point has a neighborhood that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

He said arctan is a good choice because its homeomorphic properties are easy to work with.

Comment: It is fairly straightforward to establish a homeomorphism between $B(0,1)$ and any other ball $B(x_0,r)$. Similarly between $B(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$. So this gives $B \Leftrightarrow C$.

Comment: These are the kind of family discussions I can get into.

Comment: Shouldn't that read $A\iff B\iff C$ or $A\Rightarrow B\Rightarrow C\Rightarrow A$?

Answer (score 3):

Write things in polar coords. Suppose you have a map from a nhd of your point to all of $R^n$ (Prop C). Then compose this with a map that sends

$$
rs
$$
where $r \in [0, \infty)$ and $s \in S^{n-1}$ to 
$$
\frac{2R}{\pi}\arctan(r) s.
$$

This maps $R^n$ to a unit disk, and hence the composite maps your nhd to a unit disk instead of to $R^n$. You can do the rest, I bet...

Comment: Ah, that's very clever. Thanks a lot.